# Função php - Trabalhando com valores de moedas

Tags: php

Boa noite ,
gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver um problema.
Pesquisando um pouco aqui acabei encontrando um código que vai me ajudar no trabalho com uma página para cadastro de gasto e renda.

Gostaria de fazer com que esse código não arredondasse os valores.
quando digito 0,3 centavos ele retorna 1. Se eu digito 0.030 ele volta 1 também e assim por diante. 
Gostaria de poder trabalhar com as casas decimais corretas pois se não os valores finais não vão bater com minhas notas.

```
    function format_amount($n, $n_decimals) {
    return ((floor($n) == round($n, $n_decimals)) ? number_format($n).'.00' : number_format($n, $n_decimals));
}
```

Desde já agradeço.

Fonte: https://github.com/santanumajumdar/MoneyManager/blob/master/includes/Functions.php

Answer (score 1):

> A função `round()` é quase idêntica a função `number_format()`. A
>   diferença é que a segunda adiciona zeros à direita do número se o
>   valor do segundo parâmetro for maior que a quantidade de casas
>   decimais do primeiro parâmetro. Caso o segundo parâmetro seja omitido ou for igual a `0`, o número será arredondado para o próximo inteiro, se a decimal for igual ou maior que `.5`, ou para o anterior, se a decimal for menor que `.5`.
>
> Exs.:
>
> ```
> round(0.3,2); retorna 0.3
> number_format(0.3,2); retorna 0.30
> round(0.35); retorna 0
> number_format(0.35); retorna 0
> round(0.55); retorna 1
> number_format(0.51); retorna 1
> ```

Primeira sugestão é retirar da função `format_amount($n, $n_decimals)` a condicional dentro do `return`, que se torna desnecessária, deixando apenas `return number_format($n, $n_decimals);`, desta forma:

```
function format_amount($n, $n_decimals) {
    return number_format($n, $n_decimals);
}
```

A segunda <s>sugestão</s> é **nunca** enviar `$n_decimals` como 0 ou um número menor do que a quantidade de casas decimais do número em `$n`. Caso isso não seja observado, há risco de arredondamento. Veja:

```
format_amount('0.3', '1') // ok! 1 casa decimal e 1. Irá retornar 0.3
format_amount('0.3', '2') // ok! 1 casa decimal e 2. Irá retornar 0.30

format_amount('0.35', '1') // errado! 2 casas decimais e 1. Irá retornar 0.4
format_amount('0.353', '2') // errado! 3 casas decimais e 2. Irá retornar 0.35
format_amount(0.353,0); // errado! 3 casas decimais e 0. Irá retornar 0 (igual a round)
format_amount(0.553,0); // errado! 3 casas decimais e 0. Irá retornar 1 (igual a round)
format_amount(0.557,2); // errado! 3 casas decimais e 2. Irá retornar 0.56 (igual a round)
```

Comment: Essa questão do format_amount seria usado como ? Fiquei confuso com isso. Não vou nega.
E obrigado pela primeira dica.

Comment: @RafsQ O format_amount recebe 2 parâmetros, certo? O primeiro é o número, o segundo é o número de casas decimais que vc quer tratar. Se você enviar no segundo parâmetro um número menor do que o número de casas decimais enviado no primeiro parâmetro, pode haver arrendondamento. Por ex., se eu enviar format_amount('3,5','2'), irá retornar "3,50", por que eu informei no segundo parâmetro que quero 2 casas decimais... se eu enviar format_amount('3,55','1'), estou informando que quero apenas 1 casa decimal, aí neste caso irá retornar "3,6", porque o último número decimal é 5...

Comment: O que não entendi @ÐvÐ, é como usar nessa função ai.Estou sem saber configurar essa função para que ela retorne o valor como você explicou.
Estou "apanhando" para isso no modo como usar dentro do que já está criado.

Comment: @RafsQ Quais os valores que vc irá mandar para a função? Podem variar? Se for isso, eu posso reescrever a função de modo que possa retornar qualquer valor que vc mandar sem arrendondamentos.

Comment: Eu tenho um input, um formulário onde esse valor é colocado.No momento que estou preenchendo os valores ele só começa a colocar a vírgula depois do 4 dígito.Exemplo : 1,111. Se for só 111 ele recebe 111 como foi digitado sem acrescentar os ,00. Essa função vai ser executada em cima desse input e passar o valor para o banco. 
Dessa forma que você me explicou eu retorno valores de acordo com o que digito no campo. Sobre os valores: Se eu digitar 0.30 ele retorna 1
Se eu digitar 0,030 fica errado para uma soma de dinheiro apesar de o valor ir como foi digitado.

Comment: @RafsQ Vou refazer a função para receber apenas 1 parametro, o número, e retornar as decimais automaticamente com 3 dígitos

Comment: Ok, @ÐvÐ
Estou aqui estudando e pesquisando para entender tudo isso.

Comment: @RafsQ criei uma função onde vc só manda os números e ele retorna com as decimais sem arrendondar. Veja: https://ideone.com/X9bBmn

Comment: Mais uma vez muito obrigado @ÐvÐ. Mas o negócio é o seguinte. Continua não dando certo. Na página que eu lanço um valor (ex: página de gastos) quando eu digito 0.30 ao invés de 0,30 ele aceita o valor digitado mas arredonda. Continuo não conseguindo mesmo depois de ajuda.E mais uma vez, obrigado moral.

Comment: @RafsQ De nada! Considere marcar  ✓ se a resposta foi útil. Abs!